# Access local domain from another machine in the same net work

Tags: apache

I use local domain like this below.

`/etc/hosts`

127.0.0.1       my.koala.com

for apachec setting

`httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName my.koala.com
    DocumentRoot /Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/my/public
    <Directory /Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/my/public>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Now I want to access this from the mobile in the same network.

My local pc ip is `192.168.2.127`

Is it possible to access??

Or what is the good practice for this environment??

Answer (score 0):

1. You could perhaps modify [hosts file on the phone](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20hosts) to point your domain name to 192.168.2.127.
2. If you have local DNS server in your network, you coould add `A` record that would point your domain name to that ip address, but that would then affect all devices on your network. (also, you probably want to make sure that your IP address is fixed so you don't have to modify DNS each time address changes)